# Naive Bayes All columns HAVE TO be Factor? or not

Tags: r, bayesian

I am trying to understand how is Naive Bayes working.

I have a dataset looks like this:

```
> data.flu
    chills runnyNose headache fever flu
1      1         0        M     1   0
2      1         1        N     0   1
3      1         0        S     1   1
4      0         1        M     1   1
5      0         0        N     0   0
6      0         1        S     1   1
7      0         1        S     0   0
8      1         1        M     1   1
```

If the types of those columns look like this:

```
str(data.flu)
'data.frame':  8 obs. of  5 variables:
  $ chills   : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
$ runnyNose: num  0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
$ headache : Factor w/ 3 levels "M","N","S": 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 1
$ fever    : num  1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
$ flu      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2
```

The model will looks like this:

```
Naive Bayes Classifier for Discrete Predictors
Call:
  naiveBayes.default(x = X, y = Y, laplace = laplace)
A-priori probabilities:
  Y
0     1 
0.375 0.625 

Conditional probabilities:
  chills
Y        [,1]      [,2]
0 0.3333333 0.5773503
1 0.6000000 0.5477226
...
```

I am just so interesting to find that `P(chills=1|flu=1) + P(chills=0|flu=1) != 1`, in my point of view, when the `flu` is positive, a person either has chills or not.. Something absolutely went wrong against my elementary knowledge of probability.

I verified my thought by changing all the types to factors and every number matches my handy calculation.

```
A-priori probabilities:
  Y
0     1 
0.375 0.625 

Conditional probabilities:
  chills
Y           0         1
0 0.6666667 0.3333333
1 0.4000000 0.6000000
...
```

Can anyone explain to me how is the probabilities in the first scenario calculated when the columns contains numeric columns... It will also be super helpful pointing me to any book or paper.

Many thanks

Comment: Why not simply start with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Parameter_estimation_and_event_models)?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions: All categorical columns have to be factors, otherwise they are treated as numericals.

Assuming you are using the e1071 package, see the [documentation](http://www.ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/e1071/html/naiveBayes.html)

> A list of tables, one for each predictor variable. For each categorical variable a table giving, for each attribute level, the conditional probabilities given the target class. For each numeric variable, a table giving, for each target class, mean and standard deviation of the (sub-)variable.

This means, that in the first example, you are not seeing the conditional probabilities for P(chills=1|flu=0) and P(chills=0|flu=0), but rather the mean and standard deviation of chills|flu=0. Chills is then treated as continuous variable, with a normal distribution conditioned on flu.